# How to create an empty metric in Graphite?

Tags: graphite, statsd, grafana

I have three counters created from StatsD that I'm using but only one has ever been hit.
I'm trying to present all three counters in a graph in Grafana but Grafana doesn't treat non-existent metrics.
What's the best way to add an empty counter to Graphite?

Comment: Never done that, but perhaps you can 0-increment a counter? `echo "foo:0|c" | nc -u -w0 127.0.0.1 8125`

Comment: hmm... you want to present no existence counter! How do you think it should be presented?

Comment: @kwarunek As a metric with a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Manually send the metric as a 0 counter as @dukebody says. This will create an entry for the metric in whisper so, although empty, the metric will exist.